# PHP - Count $_POST items and store them in an array

Tags: php, arrays, http-post

**PLOT :** I'm working on a quiz .
The quiz has an UNKNOW number of questions .
The name of each question / input is : question1 , question2, question3 and so on . (all inputs are radio inputs with a yes/no answer)
I'm sending the form to a php file .

**QUESTION :** How do I code a php line so that I can count the $_POST items and store them in an ARRAY ?

i got stuck at : foreach($_POST as $key -> $value)

Answer (score 2):

Ummm:

```
$allPosts = $_POST;
$countPosts = count($allPosts);
```

Comment: But `$POST` will contain more than _just_ the radio button values; for instance, you're potentially including the value of the submit button also.

Comment: well .. $_POST['xx'] = $allPosts['xx'] . I wanted to get something like $allPosts['0'] = post value number one .